# Filling web forms with Selenium, Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to fill [this form](https://quintadb.com/widgets/cCsqTdWRnaWPBdGb4zgCkg/c_mw7dRmneW4mgWQzrFdOq) to improve my job, i tried with Selenium but something goes wrong:

```
driver= webdriver.Chrome('/Users/48604/Desktop/kyk/chromedriver')
driver.get('https://quintadb.com/widgets/cCsqTdWRnaWPBdGb4zgCkg/c_mw7dRmneW4mgWQzrFdOq')
fill = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='dtype[cTqIlcPGbjsk_cIuZdPSoQ]' and @id='dtype_cTqIlcPGbjsk_cIuZdPSoQ']").click()
fill.send_keys('test')
```

but i am getting error:

> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such
> element: Unable to locate element:
> {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@name='dtype[cTqIlcPGbjsk_cIuZdPSoQ]'
> and @id='dtype_cTqIlcPGbjsk_cIuZdPSoQ']"}

I tried as well:

```
 fill = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='dtype[cTqIlcPGbjsk_cIuZdPSoQ]' and @id='dtype_cTqIlcPGbjsk_cIuZdPSoQ']").click()[0]
```

but still not working, any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Bring `.click()` to the next line:

```
fill = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='dtype[cTqIlcPGbjsk_cIuZdPSoQ]' and @id='dtype_cTqIlcPGbjsk_cIuZdPSoQ']")
fill.click()
fill.send_keys('test')
```

Output:

[image]

Your code didn't work because you have assigned the output of the `.click()` function to the variable `fill`. When you print out the type of fill in your code, this is what it prints:

```
fill = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='dtype[cTqIlcPGbjsk_cIuZdPSoQ]' and @id='dtype_cTqIlcPGbjsk_cIuZdPSoQ']").click()
print(type(fill))
```

Output:

```
<class 'NoneType'>
```

And a variable of type `NoneType` does not have a function called `.send_keys()`. Hence, your code didn't work.